# getting the current traffic status through Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gis, directions, driving-directions

If I am travelling from one place to another and using driving directions from Google Map API
How can I calculate traffic status during travelling using Google Map API?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the traffic data with current APIs. The `Distance Matrix API` or `Directions API` takes traffic into account, but you can't get the data for the actual traffic.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/), the Distance Matrix API allows Google Maps API for Business users to input `departure_time` in order to get a travel time estimates ("trip duration") considering current traffic conditions.